# Espressioni familiari di augurio per una persona malata

Tags: phrase-request

Cosa si potrebbe dire a un amico o a una persona con cui si ha certa confidenza o familiarità quando si sa che è malata? Io conosco soltanto queste due espressioni:

> - Rimettiti presto!
> - Rimettiti bene!

Ce ne sono altre?

E, incontrando quella persona qualche giorno dopo, potrei chiederle, per cercare di informarmi sullo suo stato di salute:

> - Ti sei rimesso bene?

Potreste suggerire qualche alternativa?

Comment: Nel secondo caso potresti dire: *Come stai? Ti sei ripreso (dalla malattia)?* oppure “*Sei guarito”?* o “*Ti sei rimesso in forma*”?

Comment: Grazie, @Hachi.   La frase "Ti sei ripreso?" immagino corrisponda a la definizione seguente del [Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/riprendere): «Con uso rifl., *riprendersi*, di persone, riaversi, tornare in sé, nella propria integrità fisica e morale: *ebbe uno svenimento, ma si riprese subito*; *la malattia l’aveva indebolito molto, ma ora s’è ripreso*; *dopo la morte del figlio non s’è più ripresa*».

Comment: Sì, esatto......

Answer (score 2):

Diciamo che l'espressione più usata per augurare una buona guarigione a livello informale come hai detto tu è *"Rimettiti presto"*. Se è una persona con cui hai una certa confidenza e potresti utilizzare un tono "sarcastico" del tipo:

> *"Vedi di guarire presto!"*
> *"Mi raccomando, guarisci in fretta/sbrigati a guarire!"*

Per quanto mi riguarda non ho mai sentito dire "*Rimettiti bene*" ma non escluderei la sua esistenza...

Invece nel secondo caso potresti usare:

- *"Come sta andando?"*
- *"Va/stai meglio?"*
- *"Come procede la guarigione?"*
- *"Com'è/come va/come stai? Ti sei ripreso?"*

Se può esserti utile ho trovato questo articolo con molte frasi che potresti utilizzare:
[Frasi per augurare una pronta guarigione](https://www.notiziesecche.it/augurare-pronta-guarigione-frase/).

Comment: “Rimetti presto” non è un grande augurio... ;) (so che è un refuso).

Comment: Grazie, Liiuc. Volevo fare la stessa osservazione di @DaG: immagino sia "rimettiti", no? E poi... fino a che punto   "Vedi di guarire presto!" è giudicato come sarcastico?

Comment: Le espressioni che appaiono su quel sito web sono veramente "raccomandabili"? Non mi sembrano cose da dire direttamente a una persona, perlomeno in modo spontaneo e naturale, magari sono messaggi da scrivere... e non saprei dire se qualcuno sia piuttosto di cattivo gusto...

Comment: Un'ultima domanda riguardo al tuo suggerimento "Com'è?": ha lo stesso significato di "Come stai?".

Comment: Sì, @Charo, “Com'è” non è standard. Sembra più che uno stia chiedendo spiegazioni su qualcosa: “Sai, ieri sono licenziato.” “Davvero? Com'è?”

Comment: @Charo tento di rispondere a tutte le tue domande... Allora per quanto riguarda "Rimettiti" ho corretto (scusate, errore di battitura)... Per quanto riguarda le espressioni del sito, ovviamente non sono stato lì a controllare ogni singola frase, molte sono anche formali e andrebbero usate solo per scritto.

Comment: @Charo, per quanto riguarda "Vedi di guarire presto!", ho scritto *sarcastico* perchè purtroppo una persona non puo' decidere quando guarire (altrimenti non ci sarebbe più nessun malato ;D).... diciamo che è un modo "simpatico" (lasciatemi il termine) per far capire alla persona con cui parliamo che teniamo al suo stato di salute

Comment: Per quanto riguarda "Com'è? ", sì, puoi tranquillamente sostituirlo con "come stai"... Diciamo che è un modo più informale di chiedere come stai. **Credo** derivi  da "Com'è la vita?" (quindi come essere la tua vita ?)

Comment: Non consiglierei di imparare l'italiano da un sito che scrive cose come “esserti affianco”...

Comment: Parte 1. Guarisci presto; Parte 2. Come va?; Come stai?; Come ti senti?